# Can't parse some content using a customized method

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've written a script using scrapy to get the `name`, `phone` number and `email` from a website. The content I'm after are available in two diferent links, as in `name` and `phone` in one link and the `email` is in another link. I've used here `yellowpages.com` as an example and tried to implement the logic in such a way so that I can parse the `email` even when I'm in it's landing page. It's a requirement that I can't use ***meta***. However, I used `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` in combination with scrapy to accomplish the job complying the above condition but it is real slow.

Working one (along with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`):

```
import scrapy
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

def get_email(target_link):
    res = requests.get(target_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    email = soup.select_one("a.email-business[href^='mailto:']")
    if email:
        return email.get("href")
    else:
        return None

class YellowpagesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yellowpages"
    start_urls = ["https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee+Shops&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA"]

    def parse(self,response):
        for items in response.css("div.v-card .info"):
            name = items.css("a.business-name > span::text").get()
            phone = items.css("div.phones::text").get()
            email = get_email(response.urljoin(items.css("a.business-name::attr(href)").get()))
            yield {"Name":name,"Phone":phone,"Email":email}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    })
    c.crawl(YellowpagesSpider)
    c.start()
```

I'm trying to mimic the above concept without `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` but can't make it work.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class YellowpagesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yellowpages"
    start_urls = ["https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee+Shops&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA"]

    def parse(self,response):
        for items in response.css("div.v-card .info"):
            name = items.css("a.business-name > span::text").get()
            phone = items.css("div.phones::text").get()
            email_link = response.urljoin(items.css("a.business-name::attr(href)").get())

            #CANT APPLY THE LOGIC IN THE FOLLOWING LINE

            email = self.get_email(email_link)
            yield {"Name":name,"Phone":phone,"Email":email}

    def get_email(self,link):
        email = response.css("a.email-business[href^='mailto:']::attr(href)").get()
        return email

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    })
    c.crawl(YellowpagesSpider)
    c.start()
```

***How can I make my second script work mimicking the first script?***

Comment: Why can't you use `request.meta`? It's the appropriate tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `response.meta`, but if is required to avoid it, ok, let's try in another way: check lib https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-inline-requests/

```
from inline_requests import inline_requests


class YellowpagesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yellowpages"
    start_urls = ["https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee+Shops&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA"]

    @inline_requests
    def parse(self, response):
        for items in response.css("div.v-card .info"):
            name = items.css("a.business-name > span::text").get()
            phone = items.css("div.phones::text").get()

            email_url = items.css("a.business-name::attr(href)").get()
            email_resp = yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(email_url), meta={'handle_httpstatus_all': True})
            email = email_resp.css("a.email-business[href^='mailto:']::attr(href)").get() if email_resp.status == 200 else None
            yield {"Name": name, "Phone": phone, "Email": email}
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks @vezunchik for your awesome solution. Make sure to add `yield` before `scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(email_url))`.